# Error JPA SPRING JBOSS Configuration Missing PersistenceUnitMetadata (thread local wasn't set)

Tags: jpa, jboss

I'm tryning an integration of SPRING JPA (Hibernate Implementation ) on existant Java EE Project with INFORMIX database.

I have this error

```
10:18:27,982 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."sigems-ear-dme.ear/sigems-ihm-dme.war#blDpiPersistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."sigems-ear-dme.ear/sigems-ihm-dme.war#blDpiPersistenceUnit": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: vfs:/D:/Developpement/Produits/DME/Tools/Server/jboss711/standalone/deployments/sigems-ear-dme.ear/sigems-ihm-dme.war/WEB-INF/classes/
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS011455: Missing PersistenceUnitMetadata (thread local wasn't set)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getClassesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:208)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:484)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what JBAS011455 is, but try to override the metadata by modifying the app bundled JBoss XML

[Overriding metadata through XML](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html)